# Como se hace para enviar los datos que tengo en mongodb ya creados por node js a un endpoint o pagina?

Tags: nodejs, visual-studio, reactjs, mongodb

Estoy empezando en esto recien y tengo algunas dudas .Comento tengo una base de datos creada  que tiene unos productos y esos tienen a su vez precio , stock , etc  quiero hacer una lista y mostrarla en una primer pagina , y despues quiero que al hacer click muestre detalles de ese dato . El problema es que no encuentro en internet un tutorial , lo que quiero hacer es que los datos que importe a la base de datos que los estoy viendo en compass me los traiga al endpoint o a la pagina que le quiero asignar /products. Y de eso en esa pagina cuando le haga click me muestre el detalle del producto seleccionado con el evento click al id del producto caracteristicas etc . Por el tema es que o yo estoy entendiendo mal con los tutoriales o nose . Estoy usando moongose ahi muestro lo que estoy haciendo en captura , lo que quiero es que cuando cargue por localhost , me devuelva por postman  cuando hago me metodo post o get cualquiera de los 2.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lo quiero mostrar por get obviamente pero nose como. Vi que usaban mongoose pero no lo entendia como hacia ya que es como que lo usan para crear datos pero yo en este casos ya los tengo creados en mongo db compass .

Comment: Revisa [ask] para que veas como puedes mejorar tu pregunta, porque no das detalles de tu problema, específicamente, del por qué no aparecen datos en tu home. Agrega el código que consideres es relevante, tanto en front como backend, algún log que pueda estar mostrando desde el lado del servidor, etc. Saludos

Comment: Hola @Gaby ! Te recomiendo estos tutoriales y en general su canal: shorturl.at/egMY2

Comment: Tienes que tener 2 proyectos, cliente que sea React y Servidor que sea Node, Mongo y Express, te dejo la web de Express donde te enseñan a crear endpoints. https://expressjs.com/es/